# Вставить пробел через каждую букву и через две буквы

Tags: c#

Есть строка, например, `string stroka="string";`
мне надо вставить пробел через букву то есть на экране будет так: `s t r i n g`

Comment: А в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов как прописать код, который вставлял бы пробелы?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов подозреваю проблема в неизменямости C#-строк, к сожалению об этом очень часто рассказывают вскользь перед выдачей задания, да и слушают тоже вскользь.

Comment: @Tode несмотря на наличие ответов с рабочим кодом, рекомендую добавить в свой вопрос код вашей личной попытки решить задачу, или подробно объяснить, в чем именно была проблема. В текущем виде ваш вопрос практически бесполезен для других посетителей.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string result = String.Join(" ", stroka.AsEnumerable());
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Функция `String.Join` создает новую строку `result` из последовательности символов исходной строки (`stroka.AsEnumerable()`), используя в качестве разделителя между ними пробел.

---

Решение в общем виде:

```
var stroka = "string";

const int interval = 2; // вставка пробела каждые interval символов

var result = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < stroka.Length - 1; ++i) {
    result.Append(stroka[i]);
    if ((i + 1) % interval == 0)
        result.Append(' ');
}

if (stroka.Length > 0)
    result.Append(stroka[stroka.Length - 1]);

Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите более развёрнуто.

Comment: а если мне надо вставить пробелы через каждые 2 буквы ?

Answer (score 3):

Ок, универсальный вариант будет чуть сложнее

```
string insertingStr = "..";
string sourceStr = "qwertyuiop";
int step = 2;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(sourceStr.Substring(0, step));
for(int i = step; i < sourceStr.Length; i += step)
{
    sb.Append(insertingStr);
    for(int j = i; j < i + step && j < sourceStr.Length; j++)
    {  
        sb.Append(sourceStr[j]);
    }
}
Console.Write(sb.ToString());
```

> **Вывод:** qw..er..ty..ui..op

Можете задавать произвольную строку для вставки через каждые `step` символов исходной строки.

Отдельный бонус в отсутствии генерации паразитных строк, вне зависимости от исходных данных.

Оформить в виде отдельного метода, надеюсь, справитесь самостоятельно

---

Касательно метода [String.Insert (Int32, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx). Категорически не рекомендую его использовать в вашей задаче. Т.к. в этом случае при каждой вставке будет генерироваться новая строка. При этом нужная строка будет сформирована самой последней, а остальное свалится на плечи GC и будет ждать удаления. Просто замените тестовую строку на строку длинной в пару миллионов знаков и посмотрите на расход памяти. Тоже будет при обработке множества коротких строк в цикле.

Answer (score -1):

http://ideone.com/ukJCUE

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "string";
        string res = Regex.Replace(s, "(.)(?=.)", "$1 ");
        Console.WriteLine("==={0}===", res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Использовать регулярки для этого - из пушки по воробьям.

Comment: @Kromster, идейно - согласен. В плане производительности - неясно, надо проверять.

Comment: @Kromster, да, сильно медленно: http://ideone.com/2Kkz0y

Comment: http://ideone.com/Zy0R7l - добавил пару тестов.